# How to dynamically show/hide rows in a table

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I'm working on a website where I need to show/hide table rows. I got the feature working, but the CSS gets bad when I do show. I'm providing a [working link](http://ratingscorner.com/Mobiles/Blackberry-Bold-9000); click the 'More...' link and see the action for an example. I'm using jQuery's `toggle(slow)` for hiding and showing

I have a page built using tables:

http://ratingscorner.com/product_rating.php?alias=Rashtreeya-Vidyalaya-College-of-Engineering-Mysore-Road-Bangalore&product=colleges

If you see the section right side of image where the tick marks are there. After the tick mark the section moves to right hand side.  This happened when I did put a code to show/hide the  extra features.. any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page seems to display correctly in IE8. In Chrome and in FF the problem is that `display: block` elements inside a table make the browser render the table wrong *if* there are elements *without* `display: block` as well. A solution is either to

- set `display: block` to the first `tbody` element already (this is far the easiest solution)
- remove the `display: none` from the `.extra_properties` when showing the extra rows (and leaving the `display: block` off as well) or
- set `display: table-row-group` when showing. It's to be noted, that `display-row-group` doesn't work in IE, though.

Comment: hey thanks for the help every 1. Manually setting it display to none. did for me...

Comment: can you just see my original post and prove some help?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the problem. You have two `tbody` tags in the table. This is correct. However, when you use jQuery to show/hide the table, it applies a `display: block` attribute to the `tbody` tag which causes browser to render it incorrectly.

Use jQuery to change the display CSS attribute as follows:

- set `display: none` to hide the "more properties" section
- set `display: table-row-group` to show the "more properties" section
- OR set `display` to empty string to let browser show the section the way it should be

Comment: A - can you just see my original post and prove some help?

Answer (score -1):

what problems are you having?

```
$("tr").click(function() { $(this).hide(); }
$("#showmore").click(function() { $("#tr:hidden").show() }
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the example at all?